# Why is a bitmask (0x1F) commonly ANDed to the character encoding bytes of NFC tag NDEF payloads?

Tags: android, format, nfc, specifications, ndef

I am writing an android app to write NFC tags, and I keep seeing examples like this:

```
private NdefRecord createTextRecord(String content){
    try {
        byte[] language;
        language = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().getBytes("UTF-8");

        final byte[] text = content.getBytes("UTF-8");
        final int languageSize = language.length;
        final int textLength = text.length;
        final ByteArrayOutputStream payload = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1 + languageSize + textLength);

        payload.write((byte) (languageSize & 0x1F)); // <----- LOOK HERE
        payload.write(language, 0, languageSize);
        payload.write(text, 0, textLength);

        return new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT, new byte[0], payload.toByteArray());
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
        Log.e("createNdefMessage",e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Note the `payload.write((byte) (languageSize & 0x1F));` part. What's up with that `0x1F` bitmask? At first I thought the specification would only allow for 5 bits to describe the length of the encoding, but that doesn't make sense because we're writing a whole byte anyway.

See [here](http://www.dummies.com/consumer-electronics/nfc-data-exchange-format-ndef/) and [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pn532-rfid-nfc/ndef) for examples of the NDEF spec. And see [here](https://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2016/01/nfc-tag-writer-android.html), and [here](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-write-nfc-tag-in-android) for more examples of this mysterious `0x1F` mask being used.

Am I missing something?

EDIT: Since I have answered my own question, and I'm not entirely sure if I am correct, if anyone else can provide a better explanation, or more insight, I will select your answer instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An NDEF Text Record is a version of the generic NDEF Record structure, characterized by the Type-Name-Format (TNF field) code 1 (well-known record type names assigned by the NFC Forum) and Type-Name (TYPE field) "T" (0x54).

For the NFC Forum Well-Known Type Name "T" the structure of the NDEF Record PAYLOAD is given by the "NFC Forum Text Record Type Definition" specification.

The Text Record payload consists of a status byte, followed by a variable length language code and the actual UTF-8 or UTF-16 encoded text content. The most significant bit of the status byte is 0 for UTF-8 and 1 for UTF-16 encoding. The next bit is reserved. The 6 least significant bits indicate the number of bytes occupied by the language code. The bit mask 0x1F corresponds to the 5 least significant bits of a byte and does not match the specification text. Furthermore, the subsequent line writes `languageSize` bytes without applying the same mask, thus potentially creating an incorrect NDEF Text Record where a tail part of the language code becomes part of the text content.

As an example payload, the byte sequence `02656e48656c6c6f20576f726c64` starts with status byte 0x02 for the 2 byte language code "en" (0x65, 0x6e) followed by the UTF-8 encoded text "Hello World".

Comment: Thanks for answering. Wouldn't it be 5 bits though? `0x1F` is `11111`. Can you add a source for the information you've provided?

Comment: I found [a source](https://www.cardsys.dk/download/NFC_Docs/NFC%20Text%20Record%20Type%20Definition%20Technical%20Specification.pdf), that agrees with what you've said, but this does seem to imply that `0x1F` is the wrong mask, and should instead be `0x3F`.

Comment: That is correct, 0x1F is the wrong mask to match the specification. Though the developer of that code might have had the idea of that language codes should never be more than 31 bytes (in reality they are only a few bytes). However, that same idea applied to parsing incoming data would go terribly wrong. Anyway I'll have to update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a comment in the code [here](https://github.com/devnied/EMV-NFC-Paycard-Enrollment/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/github/devnied/emvnfccard/utils/TlvUtil.java) ...

```
byte MASK = (byte) 0x1F;
if ((tagFirstOctet & MASK) == MASK) { // EMV book 3, Page 178 or Annex B1 (EMV4.3)
```

... I was able to find a partial answer to my question on [page 156 of EMV 4.3 Book 3](https://www.emvco.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/EMV_v4.3_Book_3_Application_Specification_20120607062110791.pdf).

It seems that the lower 5 bits describe the encoding, are for a `tag number`, and the first 3 bits describe the `class` and `object`, thusly:

```
b8 | b7 | b6 | b5 | b4 | b3 | b2 | b1 | Meaning
---------------------------------------------------------------
 0 |  0 |    |    |    |    |    |    | Universal class
 0 |  1 |    |    |    |    |    |    | Application class
 1 |  0 |    |    |    |    |    |    | Context-specific class
 1 |  1 |    |    |    |    |    |    | Private class
   |    |  0 |    |    |    |    |    | Primitive data object
   |    |  1 |    |    |    |    |    | Constructed data object
   |    |    |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 | See subsequent bytes
   |    |    |   Any other value <31  | Tag number

According to ISO/IEC 8825, Table 36 defines the coding rules of the 
subsequent bytes of a BER-TLV tag when tag numbers ≥ 31 are used
(that is, bits b5 - b1 of the first byte equal '11111').

b8 | b7 | b6 | b5 | b4 | b3 | b2 | b1 | Meaning
---------------------------------------------------------------
 1 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Another byte follows
 0 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Last tag byte
   |           Any value > 0          | (Part of) tag number
```

So, it seems as if the suggestion to use `(languageSize & 0x1F)` is incorrect, at least for the following reasons:

1. This value should represent a tag number, not the character encoding.
2. It assumes every tag is `universal class` and `primitive data`
3. If the lower 5 bits are all 1 (ie: the value is 31), the format will be incorrect because the next byte should describe the number.

Since I have answered my own question, and I'm not entirely sure if I am correct, if anyone else can provide a better explanation, or more insight, I will select your answer instead.